# How to select and retrieve column with checkbox control with javafx

Tags: java, checkbox, tableview, javafx-2, javafx

In my `Javafx2` application I have a `TableView` in which I want to have `CheckBoxes` to select one or many column.

I find many answer to make an entire column dedicated for checkbox by row, but in my case, i want to add a checkbox for each column label in order to select only the column checked when the user clic on a button for computate a row.

I see there is a `javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell<S,T>` but i can i use it for tableview column selection ?

Is it possible ?

**Update 1 :**

Thanks to @amru, it's possible to add `Node` into header of `TableColumn` object. 
So i have another question, what is the best way to retrieve indexes of all selected column ? As far as I'm concerned, i search also in javafx api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will put a checkbox in the column header.

```
column.setGraphic(new CheckBox());
```

UPDATED:
Set the checkbox's user data with the column. You can retrieve it later when user ticked the checkbox.

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) event.getSource();
            TableColumn column = (TableColumn) cb.getUserData();
            if (cb.isSelected()) {
                lstClm.add(column);
            } else {
                lstClm.remove(column);
            }
            for (TableColumn clm : lstClm) {
                System.out.println("selected column: " + clm.getText());
            }
        }
    };
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    cb.setUserData(firstDataColumn);
    cb.setOnAction(handler);
    firstDataColumn.setGraphic(cb);

    cb = new CheckBox();
    cb.setUserData(secondDataColumn);
    cb.setOnAction(handler);
    secondDataColumn.setGraphic(cb);
```

Comment: Thanks ! Do you have an idea on how i can get the id of column selected with a listener ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. the lstClm variabel type is List<TableColumn>

Comment: Great answer thanks, but i have one more question, how do you know at which index you remove your column in the list if user untick ? i'm ok for the add operation, but for the remove ?

Comment: I remove the column not using index. But using the column object itself taken from checkbox's user data . If you mean you need to know the index of the column in the list, you can use `lstClm.indexOf(column)`